# docker image is running but webpage error - Docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-machine

I have a basic django project and I am trying to get it running locally through docker. I have the docker file. I build the docker image. I ran the docker image. It is running, but my webpage shows an error on the screen like it is not connecting to the docker server... Here is what I have:

docker file:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR general
COPY requirements.txt ./
EXPOSE 8000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here is how I am buiding and running this project:

```
omars-mbp:split omarjandali$ docker build -t splitbeta/testing2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  223.7kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3
 ---> 79e1dc9af1c1
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR general
 ---> 04a6f8a7f92a
Removing intermediate container b2ffb485e485
Step 3/7 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> 649d77ec499e
Step 4/7 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in 7d8d6fe8de1d
 ---> c328d885a5f1
Removing intermediate container 7d8d6fe8de1d
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 1c9aca43dc14
Collecting Django==1.11.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
Collecting gunicorn==19.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading gunicorn-19.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114kB)
Collecting pytz (from Django==1.11.5->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (511kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, Django, gunicorn
Successfully installed Django-1.11.5 gunicorn-19.6.0 pytz-2017.3
 ---> 602e88557c8b
Removing intermediate container 1c9aca43dc14
Step 6/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 55cff629cb51
Step 7/7 : CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
 ---> Running in efd75f8fb602
 ---> 2cef664a626d
Removing intermediate container efd75f8fb602
Successfully built 2cef664a626d
Successfully tagged splitbeta/testing2:latest
omars-mbp:split omarjandali$ docker run -d spltibeta/testing2
```

Here is the project running:

```
omars-mbp:split omarjandali$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
fc14f03a18b0        splitbeta/testing2   "python manage.py ..."   3 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        8000/tcp            loving_volhard
```

THe webpage is giving the following error when it is supposed to display a template page....

```
This site can’t be reached

127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

I got it running yesterday but it is not working any more... I dont know why. I didnt change anything

I am logged into my dockerhub account in my terminal

Comment: Just to verify: you try to connect to port 8000 with your browser, right?

Comment: yeah I am using `120.0.0.1:8000/users` @SörenWeber

Comment: I tried it and it did the same thing. This was happening yesterday and i did something that got it working, but I cant remember how I got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your Docker run command doesn't publish port 8000. By default, docker won't publish any container ports on the host system if you don't tell it to explicitly. Try using the [-p or --publish option of docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose):

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 spltibeta/testing2
```

Alternatively, you can use the -P or --publish-all option to publish all exposed ports of your container on your host system. This will assign a random port on the host.

```
docker run -d -P spltibeta/testing2
```

Comment: I tried it and it did the same thing. This was happening yesterday and i did something that got it working, but I cant remember how I got it working

Comment: I am not typing `omars-mbp:split omarjandali$ docker run --name splitbeta_test2 -t splitbeta_test2` and then I am getting the message `Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 15, 2017 - 00:43:12
Django version 1.11.5, using settings 'split.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.` which meas that the server is running, but on the webpage I am still get the errror message. why is that happening

Comment: To me it still seems like the port isn't published on the host system. Try using the [docker port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/) argument to see your mapped ports. Maybe this gives a hint?

Comment: I am getting `omars-mbp:split omarjandali$ docker port inspiring_goodall 8000/tcp
Error: No public port '8000/tcp' published for inspiring_goodall`

Comment: so there is not port being published for this image?? how can I publish a port. but the django `python manage.py runserver` from the docker file is supposed to publish the port.... so how can I do this so that the port is published

Comment: You publish ports by using the options I described in the answer above. ;-) Django runs in a Docker container and can't decide which ports get published on your host system. You have to specify that when running a container.

Comment: when i build the image, it keeps using the cashe can i clear the cache or does it not make a difference

Comment: I am just super frustrated because I got it working yesterday and now I cant get it running

Comment: Ignoring the build-cache of Docker won't help you probably since Django seems to be running without a problem. I would see it as a networking problem and try to find out why you can't reach the port inside your container.

Comment: What does `docker port <container>` report when you use a publish option from my answer?

Comment: it doesnt display anything... `omars-mbp:helloworld omarjandali$ docker port dazzling_hypatia
omars-mbp:helloworld omarjandali$`

Comment: it just goes to the next line. it is building and running the image but for some reason that I cant figure out for the life of me, there is no connection with the server. I got it running yesterday right before I slept but now it is not doing anything and i can figure this out. it is getting annoying for me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159016/discussion-between-soren-weber-and-omar-jandali).

Comment: I just edited my answer so it shows how to map to a specific port on the host system. My previous answer resulted in a mapping to a random port.